# any one who will help on yii2 dynamic form

Tags: php, mysql, yii2-advanced-app

While I am using wbraganca dynamic form,the following errors are happening.
please please help me as much as possible.

1. inserting data and clicking Create button it doesn't show me the view page, it displays simple a blank page. like this view page is not displayed
2. database stores a null value
3. gridview displayes a "[not set]" value

form.php

```
 use yii\helpers\Html;
 use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
 use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
 use frontend\models\Items;
 use frontend\models\Employees;
 use frontend\models\Departments;
 use dosamigos\datepicker\DatePicker;
 use wbraganca\dynamicform\DynamicFormWidget;
 /* @var $this yii\web\View */
 /* @var $model backend\models\Borrow */
 /* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
  $js = '
     jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterInsert", function(e, item) {

    jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper .panel-title- address").each(function(index) {

    jQuery(this).html("Borrows: " + (index + 1))
    });

  });


   jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterDelete", function(e) {

   jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper .panel-title-address").each(function(index)    
   {

      jQuery(this).html("Borrows: " + (index + 1))

    });

   });

   ';

   $this->registerJs($js);
   ?>
   <div class="borrow-form">
   <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id'=>'dynamic-form']); ?>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
        <?= $form->field($model,'dept_id')->dropDownList(
          ArrayHelper::map(Departments::find()->all(),'id','dept_name'),
            ['prompt'=>'select departments'])
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <?=$form->field($model, 'return_date')->widget(
            DatePicker::className(), [
            'inline' => false, 
            'clientOptions' => [
            'autoclose' => true,
            'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
            ]
        ]);?>
    </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="padding-v-md">

     <div class="line line-dashed"></div>

     </div>
    <!-- beginning of dynamic form -->
    <?php DynamicFormWidget::begin([
    'widgetContainer' => 'dynamicform_wrapper', // required: only alphanumeric characters plus "_" [A-Za-z0-9_]
    'widgetBody' => '.container-items', // required: css class selector
     'widgetItem' => '.item', // required: css class
     'limit' => 10, // the maximum times, an element can be added (default 999)
    'min' => 1, // 0 or 1 (default 1)
    'insertButton' => '.add-item', // css class
    'deleteButton' => '.remove-item', // css class
    'model' => $modelsAddress[0],
    'formId' => 'dynamic-form',
    'formFields' => [
    'items_id',
    'unit',
    'request',
    'allowed',
     ],
    ]); ?>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i> Items              
    </h4>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="container-items"><!-- widgetBody -->
    <?php foreach ($modelsAddress as $i => $modelAddress): ?>
        <div class="item panel panel-default"><!-- widgetItem -->
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title pull-left">Items</h3>
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <button type="button" class="add-item btn   btn-success btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
                    <button type="button" class="remove-item btn   btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></button>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <?php
                    // necessary for update action.
                    if (! $modelAddress->isNewRecord) {
                        echo Html::activeHiddenInput($modelAddress,   "[{$i}]id");
                    }
                ?>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <?= $form->field($modelAddress,    "[{$i}]items_id")->dropDownList(                               ArrayHelper::map(Items::find()->all(),'id','item_name'),
                        ['prompt'=>'select items']) ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <?= $form->field($modelAddress,  "[{$i}]unit")->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <?= $form->field($modelAddress, "[{$i}]request")->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
                    </div>                        

                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <?= $form->field($modelAddress, "[{$i}]allowed")->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <?= $form->field($modelAddress, "[{$i}]unit_price")->textInput(['maxlength' => true])  ?>

                    </div>
                </div><!-- .row -->
            </div>
        </div>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div><!-- .panel -->
   <?php DynamicFormWidget::end(); ?>
   <!-- end dynamic form-->

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5">                     <?=$form->field($model,'emp_id')->dropDownList(                       ArrayHelper::map(Employees::find()->all(),'id','emp_name'),
                ['prompt'=>'select employees'])
         ?>
        <?= $form->field($model,'head_id')->dropDownList(
                   ArrayHelper::map(Employees::find()->all(),'id','emp_name'),
                ['prompt'=>'select dept heads'])
         ?>
        <?= $form->field($model,'man_id')->dropDownList(
                ArrayHelper::map(Employees::find()->all(),'id','emp_name'),
                ['prompt'=>'select stoke managers'])
         ?>
        <?= $form->field($model,'keeper_id')->dropDownList(
                ArrayHelper::map(Employees::find()->all(),'id','emp_name'),
                ['prompt'=>'select stoke keepers'])
         ?>  
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">

        <?=$form->field($model, 'emp_date')->widget(
            DatePicker::className(), [
            'inline' => false, 
            'clientOptions' => [
            'autoclose' => true,
            'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
            ]
        ]);?>

        <?=$form->field($model, 'head_date')->widget(
            DatePicker::className(), [
                'inline' => false, 
                'clientOptions' => [
                'autoclose' => true,
                'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
                ]
        ]);?>

        <?=$form->field($model, 'man_date')->widget(
            DatePicker::className(), [
                'inline' => false, 
                'clientOptions' => [
                'autoclose' => true,
                'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
                ]
        ]);?>

        <?=$form->field($model, 'keeper_date')->widget(
            DatePicker::className(), [
                'inline' => false, 
                'clientOptions' => [
                'autoclose' => true,
                'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
                ]
        ]);?>
       </div>                  
       </div>  
     <div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update',   ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
   </div>

  <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

controller.php

```
   namespace frontend\controllers;
   use Yii;
   use frontend\models\Borrow;
   use frontend\models\BorrowSearch;
   use yii\web\Controller;
   use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
   use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
   use frontend\models\Items;
   use frontend\models\Model;
    /**
   * BorrowController implements the CRUD actions for Borrow model.
   */
   class BorrowController extends Controller
   {
   /**
    * @inheritdoc
    */
   public function behaviors()
    {
     return [
      'verbs' => [
        'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
        'actions' => [
            'delete' => ['POST'],
        ],
    ],
   ];
  }

  /**
  * Lists all Borrow models.
  * @return mixed
  */
   public function actionIndex()
   {
    $searchModel = new BorrowSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
    'searchModel' => $searchModel,
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
   }

 /**
 * Displays a single Borrow model.
 * @param integer $id
 * @return mixed
 */
 public function actionView($id)
 {
   return $this->render('view', [
    'model' => $this->findModel($id),
   ]);
 }

 /**
  * Creates a new Borrow model.
  * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 * @return mixed
 */
 public function actionCreate()
 {
   $model = new Borrow();
   $modelsAddress = [new Borrow];
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())&& $model->save()) 
     {

      $modelsAddress = Model::createMultiple(Borrow::classname());

      Model::loadMultiple($modelsAddress, Yii::$app->request->post());
    // validate all models

    $valid = $model->validate();

    $valid = Model::validateMultiple($modelsAddress) && $valid;


    if ($valid) {

        $transaction = \Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();

        try {

            if ($flag = $model->save(false)) 
                {

                     foreach ($modelsAddress as $modelAddress) 
                        {
                          $modelAddress->items_id = $model->items_id;

                             if (! ($flag = $modelAddress->save(false))) 
                                {
                                    $transaction->rollBack();

                                    break;
                                }
                        }

                 }

            if ($flag) 
                {
                    $transaction->commit();

                    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
                }

        } catch (Exception $e) {

            $transaction->rollBack();

        }

       }

    }
    else{
     return $this->render('create', [

    'model' => $model,

    'modelsAddress' => (empty($modelsAddress)) ? [new Borrow] : $modelsAddress

    ]);

     }
  }
  /**
   * Updates an existing Borrow model.
  * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
  * @param integer $id
  * @return mixed
 */
  public function actionUpdate($id)
   {
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $modelsAddress = $model->items;

     if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())&& $model->save()) 
       {


        $oldIDs = ArrayHelper::map($modelsAddress, 'id', 'id');

        $modelsAddress = Model::createMultiple(Borrow::classname(), $modelsAddress);

        Model::loadMultiple($modelsAddress, Yii::$app->request->post());

        $deletedIDs = array_diff($oldIDs, array_filter(ArrayHelper::map($modelsAddress, 'id', 'id')));
        // validate all models

        $valid = $model->validate();

        $valid = Model::validateMultiple($modelsAddress) && $valid;

        if ($valid) 
            {

                $transaction = \Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();

                 try 
                    {

                        if ($flag = $model->save(false)) 
                            {

                                if (!empty($deletedIDs)) 
                                    {

                                        Borrow::deleteAll(['id' => $deletedIDs]);

                                    }

                                foreach ($modelsAddress as $modelAddress) 
                                    {

                                        $modelAddress->items_id = $model->id;

                                         if (! ($flag = $modelAddress->save(false))) 
                                            {

                                                $transaction->rollBack();
                                                 break;
                                            }                            
                                    }
                            }

                        if ($flag) 
                            {
                                $transaction->commit();
                                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
                             }

                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        $transaction->rollBack();

                }

            }

         }

    else
      {
        return $this->render('update', [

            'modelCustomer' => $model,

            'modelsAddress' => (empty($modelsAddress)) ? [new Borrow] : $modelsAddress
        ]);
   }
 }

   /**
   * Deletes an existing Borrow model.
   * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index'    page.
  * @param integer $id
  * @return mixed
  */
 public function actionDelete($id)
 {
   $this->findModel($id)->delete();

  return $this->redirect(['index']);
 }

   /**
   * Finds the Borrow model based on its primary key value.
   * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
   * @param integer $id
  * @return Borrow the loaded model
  * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
  */
 protected function findModel($id)
 {
  if (($model = Borrow::findOne($id)) !== null) {
    return $model;
 } else {
    throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: ok check your request reaching the controller or not in your `actionCreate` use `die('hello');`.  Just try this and let me know if you are reaching here. If you reach here then use die('hello'). by this you will know where is the problem exactly happening.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on your question.So that why I have to write answer here.

**I think problem is with your controller's create and update action.**

```
if($flag){
     $transaction->commit();
     return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
   }
```

you don't have else condition here.
To get what is the exact problem just put else condition like below.

```
if ($flag) 
  {
    $transaction->commit();
    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
  }else {
return $this->render('update', [

        'modelCustomer' => $model,

        'modelsAddress' => (empty($modelsAddress)) ? [new Borrow] : $modelsAddress
    ]);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your invaluable help.  I have tried as what you have told me. However, nothing changes yet. the problems are as usual. Can you please give me your hands on further helps. thanks again.

Comment: are you sure! you paste it in both actions??

Comment: Ya sure, I made it but no changes yet.